# Проблема с локалью в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Столкнулся с довольно странной проблемой. Есть инсталяция wp с установленным плагином Polylang.
Фронтенд двуязычный (рус/каз).
В настройках wp site language указан Русский.
При этом админка остается на 95% англоязычной, на русском только очень редкие пункты в меню, в частности "Записи" и "Страницы". Установленные плагины тоже показывают англоязычный интерфейс как в админке так и на фронте. Попытки поставить, например, немецкий, дает такой же результат.

Установленный Loco translate показывает такое предупреждение:

> English Wordpress Admin Error 
>   You only have English language
>   installed, or you are using WPML. If you only have English installed,
>   please install another language before using this plugin. Read more
>   (WordPress codex) If you are using WPML, you do not need this plugin.
>   WPML already provides a language switcher that can be configured under
>   the "Profile" tab.

Такое ощущение, что был какой-то глюк при установки wp. 
Как победить проблему?

Comment: Забудьте про фронт, скачайте русификатор для админки просто

Comment: @DaemonHK зачем ты опять суёшь нос в вопросы в которых не в зуб ногой? Нет никакого "руссифиактора для админки" в принципе.

Comment: Для начала проверь в настройках профиля юзера (не сайта!!!) установленный язык. Также убедись что в wp-content/languages/ имеются и доступны все лангпаки (они должны подтянуться когда выбирается язык в настройках), а так же не стоит плагинов для "переводов" типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/english-wp-admin/

Comment: @SeVlad ох, простите, гуру, я не правильно выразился!

Comment: @DaemonHK ты неправильно не "выразился", а в целом неправильно делаешь, что лезешь в вопросы по ВП.

Comment: Разумеется, паки на месте. Перезаливал и всякие трепыхания делал

Comment: Думаю, wp переустановить, что-ли. Непонятки.